# Is there any way to check page-rendering in Ruby-on-Rails rspec request test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test my ROR application, but I can't check page's rendering without gem.
I can only find out `.to include` method and check element.
Is there any way I can check view rendering without installing gem?

Comment: I doubt it. Something needs to pretend to be a browser and read the HTML if you want to test page content. Best you could do is test HTTP status codes.

Answer (score 0):

Is only way to use capybara gem to screenshot you html pages with:

```
page.save_screenshot('screen.png', full: true)
```